# Create rows of objects that don't rearrange

Tags: html, css

I want to create two columns of five rows, each row with an image on one side and a text box on the other. The problem I have is the elements rearrange themselves when I decrease the size of the browser window, whereas I want them to shrink in place to a minimum size and keep their formation.

Aiming for something like this https://ibb.co/fFhvo0

Could you tell me what I'm missing or have got totally wrong, thanks

```css
.about_us {
 max-width: 1600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 0;
 position: relative;
}
.about_us_container {
 max-width: 1600px;
 max-height: 370px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.about_us_background {
 width: 800px;
 height: 370px;
 min-width: 400px;
}
.about_us_image_clip {
 max-width: 800px;
 max-height: 370px;
 min-width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.about_us_image_clip img {
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="about_us">
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_image_clip" style="float: left"><img src="images/image_1.jpg" width="1600" height="740" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="about_us_background" style="float: right; background-color: #63925C"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_image_clip" style="float: right"><img src="images/image_2.jpg" width="1600" height="740" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="about_us_background" style="float: left; background-color: #63925C"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: table` on main container, and `display: table-cell` in nested spaces.

Then the main rule is that you want to have the `max-width` and `min-width` in pixels only on your main container, then manage the nested cells with % instead.

Also, to achieve that image effect that "fills" it's cell space, you want to use images as backgrounds, cause you can achieve the same effect for `<img>` with css class `object-fit: cover;` but is not supported on some browsers/versions.

So what i did was to set a class to the cells with images, like `.img1` and `.img2` and then assign the background image url using css, so you can use `background-size:cover;` instead of `object-fit: cover;` .

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0n78q1br/

```css
.about_us {
  max-width: 1600px;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.about_us_container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 370px;
}
.about_us_image_clip, .about_us_background {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  height: 370px;
  max-height: 370px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img1, .img2 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center !important;
  background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rb8Y38eilRM/maxresdefault.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="about_us">
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_image_clip img1"></div>
  <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #63925C"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #63925C"></div>
    <div class="about_us_image_clip img2"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

May use a hard coded css rules may be hard !
It can be done easily with bootstrap : [Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)